# Retrieving child from a Foreign Key in Salesforce

Tags: foreign-keys, salesforce, parent-child, apex-code, visualforce

I've a parent object (Product) and a child (Inventory). I'm trying to retrieve the value of the child object from a DisplayProducts class that I've created.

```
public class DisplayProducts {
    private Product__c products;

public DisplayProducts(Product__c item) {
    this.products = item;

}

// Properties for use in the Visualforce view
public String name {
    get { return products.Name; }
}

public String colour {
//error here 
        get { return  products.Inventorys__r.Colour__c; }

    }

public class Product {

public List<DisplayProducts> getProducts() {

        if(products == null) {
            products = new List<DisplayProducts>();

            for(Product__c item : [Select ProductID__c,Name, Price__c, (SELECT Inventory__c.Size__c, Inventory__c.Colour__c,  Inventory__c.Quantity__c FROM Product__c.Inventorys__r) 
                From Product__c WHERE ProductID__c = :prodID]) {

                products.add(new DisplayProducts(item));
            }
    }    
    return products;
}

}
```

I keep getting a compile error: invalid FK relationship.

I tried 
`products.Inventorys__r[0].Colour__c;`
but it will only retrieved the first element.

How do I retrieve the child item via the DisplayProducts Class? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please dont repost questions at both sites

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60993/invalid-foreign-key-relationship-when-retrieving-from-class